# How to find all possible lengths of a board made up from planks?

Tags: algorithm, recursion

The problem is as follows: we want to build a wooden board composed of exactly **k** planks. We're given two types of planks: shorter and longer. How to determine all possible lengths of such a board?

The solution to this problem can be found [here](https://github.com/careercup/CtCI-6th-Edition/blob/master/Java/Ch%2016.%20Moderate/Q16_11_Diving_Board/QuestionA.java).

The pseudocode is:

```
getAllLengths(k, shorterAmount, longerAmount) {
    getAllLengths(k, 0, shorterAmount, longerAmount, lenghts)
}

getAllLengths(k, totalAmount, shorterAmount, longerAmount, Set lengths) {
    if (k == 0) {
        lengths.add(total);
        return;
    }
    getAllLengths(k - 1, totalAmount + shorterAmount, shorterAmount, longerAmount, lengths);
    getAllLengths(k - 1, totalAmount + longerAmount, shorterAmount, longerAmount, lengths);
}
```

For example, using this solution if **k=3** and we have 2 shorter planks and 1 longer the possible lengths are 3,4,5,6.

I don't understand how for example we can have a board of length 6? Shouldn't there be only one possible length in the example?

Comment: I suspect the short planks are length 1, and the long planks length 2.  Therefore you can make a board of length 6 by using 3 long planks.

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz but we only have 1 long plank in the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding the question. The algorithm never takes into account how many of *each type* of plank you have, only that you have various lengths to choose from. So if you call the function:

```
allLengths(3, 1, 2)
```

You are asking how many lengths can I make using three boards of any mix of lengths one or two. If you look at both the java code and your pseudo code, this is the problem you are solving.

If you run the algorithm with k=2 and lengths of 1 and 2, you should expect:

{2, 3, 4}
   - Two or length 1
   - One of length 1 and one of length 2
   - Two of length 2.